# Route is not accessible in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let location = useLocation()
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to='/login' state={{ from: location }} />
  };

  return (component);
};

export const PublicRoute = ({ component }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!user) {
    return (component);
  };
  return <Navigate to='/dashboard' />
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
  <Route
    path='/register'
    element={<PublicRoute><Register /></PublicRoute>}
  />
  <Route
    exact
    path='/login'
    element={<PublicRoute><Login /></PublicRoute>}
  />
  <Route
    exact
    path='/dashboard'
    element={<PrivateRoute><Dashboard /></PrivateRoute>}
  />
</Routes>
```

I tried to prevent users who are already logged in from accessing the register or login page and it worked but now after logging out I am not able to access login and register pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route guards aren't passed any `component` prop. You likely meant to use the implicit `children` prop.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let location = useLocation()
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to='/login' state={{ from: location }} />
  };

  return children;
};
```

```
export const PublicRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!user) {
    return children;
  };
  return <Navigate to='/dashboard' />
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying random stuff and it started working i would still like an explanation if possible.

these were the changes i made

```
export const PublicRoute = ({Component: component}) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (user) {
    return <Navigate to='/dashboard' />
  };

  return (component );
};


      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<PublicRoute  Component={<Register/>}/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/login' element={<PublicRoute  Component={<Login/>}/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<PrivateRoute Component={<Dashboard/>}/>}/>
      </Routes>
```

Comment: The explanation is: "Now you are passing the route content on a `Component` prop *and* rendering it."

Comment: @DrewReese sorry i just started with react 3 days ago so can you please tell me why was the previous method not working. like it was working for the private route but not for the public route but just to make the code look more even i updated the private route also.

Comment: I don't think either `PrivateRoute` or `PublicRoute` worked from your post. Both components consume only a `component` prop, e.g. `({ component }) => { .... }`, but a `component` prop was not passed to it, e.g. `<PublicRoute><Register /></PublicRoute>` and `<PrivateRoute><Dashboard /></PrivateRoute>`. In both cases, `Register` and `Dashboard` are rendered as children of these route components, so their functions should be `({ children }) => { .... }` and the `children` prop value rendered.